# Put request.user.email inside another model field

Tags: python, django

I try to get user email from user model and put it in a field on another model the code is working and the counter count perfect but the add line not this is the code:

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    contain = models.TextField(blank=True)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_img", default='post_img/humanity.jpg')
    post_published = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
    post_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True)
    post_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_sponsored = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    post_sponsored_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug= slugify(self.title)
            super(Posts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Author: {self.author}, Title:{self.title}, Posted: {self.post_published}'
```

views.py

```
def post_check(request, pk):
    pos = Posts.objects.get(pk=pk)
    u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if u.sp_counter < 3:
        pos.post_sponsored = request.user.email
        u.sp_counter += 1
        u.save()
        messages.success(request, 'طلبك قيد المراجعة، الرجاء انتظار الموافقة')
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'وصلت الحد الاقصى للكفالات')
        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: You don't you use `foreign key ` instead of raw email? Foreign keys are designed for such scenarios.

Comment: `pos.save()` perhaps?

Comment: Whats the error you got?

Comment: first thank you for your response
second I don't get any errors but I want to get the user email and put it in sp_sponsored field
every time I run the code the sp_sponsored still empty
this is the problem. I hope I explain it well this time

Comment: Hi all:
I found my mistake it was that I save the user changing but not the post change.
I just add <pos.save()> and everything worked perfectly.
Its a stupid mistake I don't know how I missed it.
sorry for trouble you all.
thank you for your trying to help me